# How to have environment-specific configurations on Azure app service

Tags: .net-core, azure-web-app-service

We are migrating some of our on-site hosted web API to Azure app services. However, we aren't sure how to handle environment-specific configuration files on the Azure hosted apps.

What we do right now, in .NET Core, is include a directory of different JSON configuration files, each with the naming scheme:

`myappname.SOMEMACHINENAME.json`

Then, in the app startup, we load the appropriate file based on the machine that is running the app. This lets the app load an environment-appropriate configuration only knowing what machine it is running on.

```
Config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
  .AddJsonFile(@"Configurations\myappname." + 
    Environment.MachineName + 
    ".json", false)
  .Build();
```

However, we're not sure how to accomplish something like this in the Azure app services world, where we do not know the machine name that the app will be running on. What is the best practice method of loading an environment-specific configuration at runtime with an Azure hosted app service?

Thanks for any help!

Edited to add .NET framework info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` app setting to `CustomConfig` to the value matching `appsettings.CustomConfig.json`. Or, use a custom solution with a custom app setting. Either way, an app setting in the Azure Web App may be a good solution.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common#configure-app-settings

Comment: Thanks for the link and the suggestion, @kendaleiv! So if we add an an ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT app setting, that value is what will be returned by calls to Environment.MachineName? Or would we also need to change our logic to access this setting variable in some different way?

Comment: The `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` solution is unrelated to the machine name. My thought was assigning your own custom value via an app setting and using that to drive any necessary logic.

Comment: Ah, I see. But that would not have the desired effect for local development and testing environments, I think? It seems like there is no single value we could put in the deployable app settings file that would tell local servers what configuration to use.

Comment: Could you add the setting to `appsettings.Development.json` for local development and then override it on the Azure portal?